# EU citizens entering the UK after 29 March 2019 (policies as of 25 February 2019)

Tags: brexit

As of today, both in case of a no-deal, a yes-deal, or a delayed Brexit, will EU citizens be required upon entering the UK after 29 March 2019 to (each question is independent from the other):

- Have a visa?
- Use their passport instead of their national ID card (if they have any)?
- Fill in a landing card?
- Have their fingerprints be checked if they travel with a biometric visa?
- Have their fingerprints be checked/taken in any case?
- Justify why they come to the UK?
- If they come to the UK to visit a family member, provide any information at all about the person they're visiting (both in case they're staying at this person's place, and in case they're staying in a hotel)?
- If they come to the UK to visit a friend, provide any information at all about the person they're visiting (both in case they're staying at this person's place, and in case they're staying in a hotel)?
- In case of a positive answer to any of the preceding three questions: is this information only provided orally, informally and off-the-records to the border agent?

Comment: I voted to close as too broad since, as you point out, you're asking nearly a dozen separate questions. The format here is to ask one specific question.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what arrangements will prevail in the event that Britain leaves the EU. My understanding is that EU citizens will be allowed visa-free access, but that might not apply to all EU countries. Spain is making trouble about Gibraltar with the possible consequence that UK citizens will need a visa to visit the EU. If that happens it's likely that all EU citizens will need a visa to enter Britain. Without a negotiated withdrawal almost anything is possible. And as to the rest of your question: ‍♂️