# Will EU nationals need a UK visa way after Brexit

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, eu-citizens, brexit

Since the UK is almost out of the EU, and the detachment is almost imminent, will EU nationals need a visa for the UK for tourist vacation only?

Comment: There were similar questions before: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133310/if-uk-leaves-eu-on-march-29th-do-eu-holiday-makers-have-to-leave-the-country?rq=1 https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132846/eu-citizens-entering-the-uk-after-29-march-2019-policies-as-of-25-february-2019

Comment: No idea if this still holds: *Britain has already confirmed that EU citizens will be able to make short-term visits to the UK without a visa after Brexit takes place on 29 March* https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/brexit-news-latest-eu-visa-free-travel-agreement-no-deal-passports-a8757901.html

Comment: @BernhardDöbler 29 March doesn't hold anymore, of course, but the visa-free access for short visits does. For it to be changed, things would have to get rather more acrimonious than is likely.  But never say "never."  To cause the nationals of any EU country to require visas under existing law, the UK would have to add that country to the list of visa-required travelers.  There is no list of visa-exempt travelers.

Answer (score 3):

All publicly made statements, from both sides, have made it clear that no change for **short stays**, in the form of visas, is considered desirable.

The **Citizens’ Rights** and *transition* portions of the Withdrawal Agreement reflect only the area of **long term stays** and not **short term stays**.

The [Political declaration setting out the framework for the future relationship between the European Union and the United Kingdom](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/publications/political-declaration-setting-out-framework-future-relationship-between-european-union-and-united-kingdom_en) (22 November 2018) states:

> **IX. MOBILITY**
>   ...
>   52. In this context, the Parties aim to provide, through their domestic laws, **for visa-free travel for short-term visits**.
>   ...

At present, there are no signs that any changes relevent to **short term stays** are being taken into consideration from the British side.

---

From the European Union side, [Proposals for a Regulation amending Council Regulation 539/2001](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/european-agenda-migration/20181113_com-2018-745-proposal_en.pdf) have already been made.

Once the Withdrawal Agreement (or a no-deal Brexit) comes into effect (expected 01.02.2020 CET), in Part 1 of Annex II, the following will be inserted:

> “United Kingdom (excluding British nationals referred to in Part 3)”;

- thus the 90/180 days rule will apply for British citizens

Should the United Kingdom introduces a **visa requirement** for nationals of at least one Member State

- Artical 7 of [Regulation (EU) 2018/1806](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32018R1806#d1e688-39-1) shall apply

which would start the process for the introduction of a **visa requirement** of British citizens should no reasonable solution be found.

---

> [**What will UK travellers to the EU have to do?**](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-46564884)
>   Under **the Brexit deal**, EU citizens and UK nationals will continue to be able to **travel freely with a passport or identity card until the end of the transition period in 2020**.
>
> After this period ends, the European Commission has offered visa-free travel for UK nationals coming to the EU for a short stay, **as long as the UK offers the same in return**.

---

**Sources**:

- [Brexit: No visa but Britons will pay €7 to travel to EU countries](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-46564884)
- [Political declaration setting out the framework for the future relationship between the European Union and the United Kingdom](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/publications/political-declaration-setting-out-framework-future-relationship-between-european-union-and-united-kingdom_en)
- [Proposal for a Regulation amending Council Regulation 539/2001 - European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/european-agenda-migration/20181113_com-2018-745-proposal_en.pdf) (PDF)
- [Regulation (EU) 2018/1806](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32018R1806#d1e688-39-1)
- [EU visa reciprocity](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/MEMO_18_6822) (2018-12-19)

  - Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus <strike>, Poland</strike> and Romania have made good progress with regard to the requirements set by the U.S.
- [ETIAS Visa - European Travel Authorisation Visa - ETIAS Europe](https://www.etiaseurope.eu/)

  - The ETIAS visa is similar to the ESTA of the USA or the eTA of Canada.

Comment: It should be noted that article 7 applies to the US, but US citizens continue to enjoy visa-free travel in the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog Article 7 is a process to which the introduction of a visa requirement is the **last** step when no reasonable solution can be found. Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus and Romania still need a visa. Since November 2019 Poland does not. One must look at the **whole** picture and avoid Cherry picking.

Comment: @phoog The press release of March 2017 is a bit outdated. The one year old EU press release (link added to answer 2 hours ago)  gives a fuller picture as to the reasons why. Mainly the 3% Visa refusal rate threshold set in U.S. legislation not being fulfilled. The present 4 countries also don't fulfill the conditions to join the Schengen Area, the cause of which is similar in nature.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about cherry picking.  The US has had a visa requirement for some EU countries at least since the enlargement 15 years ago.  The European Parliament voted to impose a visa requirement on US citizens over two years ago (https://www.reuters.com/article/us-eu-usa-visa-idUSKBN1691Q9), yet there is no sign that any such requirement is actually forthcoming.  If the UK were to impose a visa requirement on some EU country, the response might be different, but it might not.

Comment: @phoog **The European Parliament voted to impose a visa requirement... ** No it did not, it **urge the Commission to adopt the necessary...** in a Non-legislative resolution. The Commission chose to continue it efforts based on Article 7 (d) and (i). The **introduction of a visa requirement** is only one option of many that Article 7 offers. And the Commission is allowed to deside which one is appropriate. (d) : **the consequences of the suspension of the exemption from the visa requirement for the external relations of the Union and its Member States with the third country in question**

Comment: @phoog The Parlament Press release quoting original resolution and the Procedure used: 
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20170227IPR64156/parliament-asks-eu-commission-to-press-for-full-us-eu-visa-reciprocity

Comment: Regardless, my point is that the chance of a visa requirement for citizens of the UK in the event of the UK introducing "a visa requirement for nationals of at least one Member State" seems rather remote, and I haven't seen anything to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Be aware of government doublespeak, the EU is threatening to introduce an "it's not a visa honest" scheme called ETIAS for all "non-visa nationals", presumablly including the post-brexit UK.

Comment: @peterGreen The ETIAS visa is similar to the ESTA of the USA or the eTA of Canada. https://www.etiaseurope.eu/

Comment: @phoog The answer states that clearly. But being Article 2 of  the referenced **Proposals for a Regulation amending Council Regulation 539/200** needs to be stated.